# Shorthand syntax to check a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

Let's say we want to check if a variable is correctly set *(not undefined, not empty, not false...)* before using it:

```
var myVar = getData();
if(myVar) {
    doSomething(myVar);
}
```

We could shorten the code by not declaring `myVar`. But, in this case, `getData()` is called twice, not ideal.

```
if(getData()) doSomething(getData());
```

---

Is there any other alternative to keep this code short but somehow clean?

Comment: What's the problem with the first example? It's short, clean and readable...

Comment: @Andreas There is no problem. I just want to know if we can have a clean short alternative. I assume that we can but I don't know the syntax.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it wouldn't even be valid as code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really get around that variable. Of course, you can also do

```
var myVar = getData();
if (myVar) doSomething(myVar);
```

or even

```
var myVar;
if (myVar = getData()) doSomething(myVar);
```

but it basically won't get better than that.

If you want to avoid introducing a variable in your scope, you can work around it by using a helper function - also if you find yourself doing this over and over:

```
function maybeDo(val, action) {
    if (val) return action(val);
}
maybeDo(getData(), doSomething);
```